# Declaring Namespaces Alias

Tags: php, import, namespaces, declaration, require

I would like to write some codes to import and 'use' (set alias) to the classes in have that are separated by namespaces.

The usual conventional method of the procedure is:

```
 require_once('/tools/toola/mytool.php');
 use tools\toola\MyTool as MyTool;
```

Will it be possible to have something like this?

```
 function import($path, $class_name) {
      $file_path = strtolower($path . '/' . $class_name . '.php');
      if(file_exists($file_path)) {
         require_once($file_path);
          use $file_path as $class_name; //Line currently throws syntax error

    } else { //file not found }    
 }
```

Hence, I can call import('/tools/toola', 'mytool'); to automate.

The line seem to have some syntax error and not fitting in well. Is there a method I can use to have the function implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.scope):

> The use keyword must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the
>   global scope) or inside namespace declarations. This is because the
>   importing is done at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be
>   block scoped.